# Putty terminal color problems for Solaris

Tags: solaris, terminal, putty, color

So I'm working on a Solaris 10 box from Putty running on Windows 7, and having a lot of trouble getting the terminal colors to work properly in actual programs like vim or tmux.

Here is the output from [256colors](https://github.com/alghanmi/terminal_color_test):

[image: Putty terminal color test]

On the left is my putty terminal connected to Solaris, on the right is running tmux. Vim has very similar problems.

I've tried changing the TERM values: xterm, xtermc, screen-256color, xterm-color, etc. The output from `tput colors` says 8, and usually 256 from within tmux.

Whats going on?

Comment: What happens when you run tmux with the `-2` flag? *-2
Force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colours*  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/getting-256-colors-to-work-in-tmux

Comment: Ah! That fixed it. I was unaware there was another flag to set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual:

> **`-2`** Force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colours